# opening csv with a single row of 6M values very slow in pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

Hi I have a file with approximately 6M comma-separated values all on one line

I am trying

```
import pandas as pd
v = pd.read_csv(file_name,
    nrows=1, skiprows=3, header=None, verbose=True, dtype=np.float32)
```

with the file being

```
Name
Tue Nov  6 13:52:15 2018 
Description
52.2269,52.2148,52.246,52.361,52.5263,52.7399,52.9738,53.1952,...45.4,
```

I get the output

> Tokenization took: 0.00 ms
>
> Type conversion took: 53023.43 ms
>
> Parser memory cleanup took: 212.13 ms

v summary shows

```
1 rows × 6316057 columns
```

The file reading time takes a lot longer than expected, I think it may be due to the data being in one row.  Is there anything I can do to speed it up, or do I need a different library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my timings below, some dummy data:

```
data = np.random.randn(1_000_000)    
with open('tmp', 'wt') as f:
    f.write('dummy\n')
    f.write('dummy\n')
    f.write('dummy\n')
    for val in data:
        f.write(str(val) + ',')
    f.write('\n')
```

In general, pandas parser is optimized for the 'long' data case, rather than a single very wide row like this.  You could pre-process the data, turning the delimiter into newlines, which for my example is ~40x faster.

```
def parse_wide_to_long(f):
    from io import StringIO
    data = open(f).read().splitlines()[-1]
    data = data.replace(',', '\n')
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)


In [33]: %timeit pd.read_csv('tmp', nrows=1, skiprows=3, header=None, dtype=np.float32)
20.6 s ± 2.04 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [39]: %timeit parse_wide_to_long('tmp')
484 ms ± 35.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: thank you so much, that's what I suspected.  I also couldn't find the option in pandas, so thank you for the IO code !